# Query to search for 2 years and exclude 1

Tags: sql, teradata

My apologies for the oddly worded question as I wasn't quite sure how I would name the title without explaining the situation.

I am currently working with a vendor table which gives a unique ID to each vendor, but the table is not normalized.

For example the ID `100000003744450`  appears multiple times in the table with a different data in each row.

There are many columns but the only ones that matter to me at the moment are the ID and the year column.  I am attempting to find the vendors who have rows for 2013, 2014 but not 2015.

So far I have:

```
select * 
from table
where ls_d_yr = '2013'
   or ls_d_yr = '2014'
```

I need to filter this results by removing any of the vendors that have the year 2013/2014 and should not have any rows with 2015 listed.

Here are the column

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you read the question, it is pretty clear @AlessandroNiciforo

Comment: the query I have gives me a partial answer as I've narrowed down the 2013 and 2014 year vendors.  But I need to remove any of the vendors from these results, that have any rows with the year 2015 outside of these results.

Comment: You mention `Aster` in a comment, `Teradata Studio` is just a client, so `Aster` or `Teradata`?

Comment: sorry I'm using Teradata studio.  I believe I am using Aster.  I'm kind of new to this application so I'm just querying as if I'm using sqldeveloper which I know isnt the smartest.

Comment: THANKS to everyone who took the time to answer! This community is awesome!

Answer (score 4):

If one of 2013 and 2014, use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude ID's having ls_d_yr in 2015.

```
select * 
from table t1
where ls_d_yr IN ('2013', '2014')
  and not exists (select 1 from table t2
                  where t2.ID = t1.ID
                    and t2.ls_d_yr = '2015')
```

If both 2013 and 2014 are required, add a `GROUP BY` and use `HAVING` to make sure two different years are provided:

```
select ID 
from table t1
where ls_d_yr IN ('2013', '2014')
  and not exists (select 1 from table t2
                  where t2.ID = t1.ID
                    and t2.ls_d_yr = '2015')
group by ID
having count(distinct ls_d_yr) = 2
```

Comment: this looks like what I should be doing. Where does the t1 or t2 come from?  I'm only querying one table.

Comment: I tried this query with my table filled in and it seems to be giving me errors.  Even with the AS added in.

Comment: t1 and t2 are table aliases. Since the same table is used twice, I give the different "instances" unique names.

Comment: Errors? Which ones? And which dbms are you using? (My answer is core ANSI SQL-99 compliant.)

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new to this site.  Is there a way to upload a screenshot in a comment?

I'm using Teradata studio to query at the moment.

Comment: You can edit the question and add your current query and the image.

Comment: Just added a couple screenshots.  Just to clarify if I wasnt specific enough.  I need ID's that have rows for BOTH 2013 and 2014 and exclude the ID's that also have a 2015.

Comment: I see. Will be back soon.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
select * 
from table AS t1
where ls_d_yr IN ('2013', '2014') AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table AS t2
                  WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID AND ls_d_yr = '2015')
```

Comment: A bit too slow. I wrote the same answer 7 seconds earlier!

Comment: ...But you seem to have bumped this one to the top, by commenting on it, @jarlh :)

Comment: tried this and replaced the table and ID column header as necessary but getting errors in aster with this query :(

Answer (score 2):

Another variation, should work in both Teradata and Aster (and probably every other DBMS):

```
select vendor
from table
where ls_d_yr in ('2013','2014','2015') -- probably numbers instead of strings?
group by vendor
having min(ls_d_yr) = '2013' -- at least one row from 2013
   and max(ls_d_yr) = '2014' -- at least one row from 2014, but none from 2015
```

Comment: @steve park: This logic is similar to Gordon's, his is more generic while mine only works for this specific scenario...

Answer (score 1):

One method for doing this uses aggregation and `having`:

```
select t.vendor
from table t
group by t.vendor
having sum(case when ls_d_yr = '2013' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when ls_d_yr = '2014' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when ls_d_yr = '2015' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause tests for one year.  The `> 0` means that one or more records exist for the year.  The `= 0` means that no record exists.

This logic is based on the statement:  "I am attempting to find the vendors who have rows for 2013, 2014 but not 2015."  I don't follow the logic in the last paragraph.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is a totally different method than what I was expecting.  I'll definitely give it a shot!

Comment: @stevepark . . . Don't be shy: What kind of error? Did you put in the correct table and column names?

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(id), ls_d_yr 
  from table 
 where ls_d_yr like '%2014%' 
    or ls_d_yr like '%2013%';
```

something like that.

Comment: this does indeed work, but I think my case needs somethign a bit more specific.  Thanks for your time!!